# Problem with same Blend behaviour applied to multiple elements

Tags: wpf, blend

I created a simple Blend behaviour to be attached to TextBox elements. It's purpose is to scroll the textbox to its end when it gets the focus, and to scroll it back to the beginning when it loses the focus.

```
 public class TextBoxScrollToEndBehaviour : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
            AssociatedObject.LostFocus += AssociatedObject_LostFocus;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = sender as TextBox;
            textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_GotFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = sender as TextBox;
            textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(double.PositiveInfinity);
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyBinding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:TextBoxScrollToEndBehaviour />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

It works great when I focus the TextBox and then I click on some other control to loose the focus. Problem is that if I switch the focus between two TextBox that share the same behaviour, the scroll is not set back to 0 on the first TextBox, even the LostFocus event is correctly triggered on it.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

.NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I found out that by replacing this line in the LostFocus event:

```
textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
```

with

```
textBox.ScrollToLine(0);
```

the behaviour works perfectly in any condition.